# How to Use Postman to Authenticate to Django REST Framework

Tags: rest, http, django-rest-framework, csrf, postman

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate to the Django REST Framework with Postman. I have a Postman interceptor. But no matter what I try, I seem to get a 403 - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

In chrome, I go to DRF's default login point. I enter the username and password and click submit. It works in Chrome. With interceptor, I can see the POST. Now if I try that *exact same* POST in Postman, I get a 403 with the CSRF error. How is that even possible? Postman is doing exactly the same thing that chrome is doing. How can it be producing a different result?

Here's me logging in from Chrome...

[image]

Here's me doing the * exact same thing* with postman...
[image]

What am I missing? I keep reading about doing a GET request, looking at the set-cookie csrf token and value, and putting that in a header on my POST request. I've tried that and every variation I can think of to no avail.

Comment: So a few seconds after I post this I figure it out of course. The problem was that the header needed to be "X-CSRFToken" not just "csrftoken". That seems very confusing and was apparently assumed knowledge... All the same, I still don't understand why the exactly same POST was working in chrome but not postman. Didn't chrome have to set that header in order for its post to work? But it wasn't in the headers chrome sent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Initially, send an HTTP GET request to the `/api/auth/login/` URL (the login page) using Postman. ***This step is important to get the `csrftoken` from the response.***

- Before HTTP GET request
  [image: before HTTP GET request]
- After sending the HTTP GET request, you will receive a **`csrftoken`** cookie as below,
  [image: HTTP get response]
- Use this value in next ***HTTP POST*** request by settings it in the request header.
  [image: HTTP post request]

---

Alternatively, you can send the csrf token along with *form-data* instead of the header, using ***`csrfmiddlewaretoken`*** key.

[image: auth using form data]

Comment: You can additionally get the value from `csrftoken` via a [Postman Test script](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-read-cookie-value-postman-request-chaining-ishan-girdhar-oscp/) and store it somewhere in your local environment, preferably marking its type as a "secret".