# Postman 403 forbidden CSRF token missing for Django Rest

Tags: flutter, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to test DRF login API on Postman but I'm getting 403 Forbidden CSRF token missing error. What I've done: Yes, I have `CsrfViewMiddleware` in settings. API works in browser but not on Postman or Flutter. I then followed these instructions: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1619/how-to-handle-postman-and-django-403-forbidden-error-csrf-verification-failed but the error remains. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: please show your postman request and django code

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fixed it. Instead of adding it to `headers` in postman I added `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to body and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the token to Headers in postman like the article suggested I added `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to Body and now I'm able to log in.

This post helped: [How to Use Postman to Authenticate to Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754485/how-to-use-postman-to-authenticate-to-django-rest-framework)